# Cannot craft Conveyor Module

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I can not craft the conveyor module, i am using 3 glass on top, 3 refined iron in the middle a electronic circuit in the bottom left and right with a battery in the bottom middle. I tried using a charged battery too without result.

I am playing "vanilla" FTB unleashed, i just installed it without turning any extra's on or off.

There is no info at all about this module: http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Conveyor_Module

Comment: "vanilla" FTB, as in, which pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If neither of the recipes work for you, there is a high chance you don't have the [GregTech mod](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/GregTech). The newest FTB version (Unleashed, 1.1.3) don't seem to have it, if I'm looking at the mod list correctly. You might try moving a bit backwards to 1.1.2 or 1.1.0.

Another solution might be adding the mod yourself, but there is always the possibility of it not being compatible. If you want to go this way, download it through a link on the wiki page and click Edit mod pack while having the pack you use selected. Afterwards, just find the downloaded files and add them.

Comment: Yeah i just downloaded gregTech and installed it into my FTB unleashed version. It gave me a warning about it massively changes the tech tree etc. I guess it is not compatible, too bad i really wanted that semi fuel generator.

Comment: if you got the warning it is compatible, it's just warning you to change your early-mid game strategy because GT changes just about every recipe

Comment: Well i still can not produce the conveyor module, and now it won't let me create a iron sword either... Currently disabling the mod to see if i can produce that iron sword again.

Comment: @MennoGouw if you can't create an iron sword then gregtech is installed correctly; use NEI to find the recipes (press R on items to find the recipe)

Comment: @ratchetfreak Hmmm ok, i will try again. Side question: Why can't i create an iron sword? And what are the alternatives?

Comment: @MennoGouw because GT changed its recipe to require more processing, you can go into the configs and turn off the hard recipes

Comment: @ratchetfreak The recipe finder of NEI works very slow so looking up stuff inside MC is not a good option. I always look them up on the wiki's where i can find additional info well ordered. But i cannot find these recipes online. Example: http://wiki.feed-the-beast.com/Tungstensteel_Sword

Comment: @ratchetfreak I am not sure this is the mod for me as it seems gregtech makes it harder and longer to get from point A to B. I am still in the middle of the learning curve for FTB so i guess this has to wait. I just wanted an automatic solution for the creosite oil the coke oven produces. gregtech's semifluid generator would have been perfect. I am going to play a little with the steam boiler but i do not want to use these things near any complicated/expensive systems due to explosion danger. I might just use it to drain the coke oven.

Comment: @MennoGouw yeah GT has a bit of a love it or hate it vibe across the community, either way it is not for beginners

Comment: @MennoGouw On one hand, GT gives you a lot more options. On the other hand, it makes everything harder and time/resource expensive. Personally I don't use it, IndustrialCraft2 without GT is complicated just enough for me.

Comment: @MennoGouw You just want to move creosote oil out of the coke oven? Are buildcraft waterproof pipes and engines not working?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie currently it is filling some tanks but yes i could just let it go into the earth, i might anger greenpeace though. But why waste all that power, filling buckets by hand to a generator goes fine and gives good EU. But i'd love to automate it.

Comment: @Menno You can use a liquid transposer to move piped fluid into buckets, letting you automate putting buckets into that generator.